# Jquery horizontal Scroll using buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to obtain horizontal scroll using buttons.

I have a container which has several divs stacked horizontally and I want to scroll through them using the buttons given.

Please take a look at my attemp and tell me what I am doing wrong.

HTML:

```
   <div class="left">
      left div
      <button id="left-button">
        swipe left
      </button>
    </div>
     <div class="center" id="content">
      <div class=internal>
        div 1
      </div>
       <div class=internal>
        div 2
      </div>
       <div class=internal>
        div 3
      </div>
       <div class=internal>
        div 4
      </div>
       <div class=internal>
        div 5
      </div>
       <div class=internal>
        div 6
      </div>
       <div class=internal>
        div 7
      </div>
       <div class=internal>
        div 8
      </div>
     </div>
    <div class="right">
    <button id="right-button">
        swipe right
      </button>
      right div
    </div>
```

JQUERY:

```
  $('#right-button').click(function() {
      event.preventDefault();
      $('#content').animate({
        marginLeft: "+=200px"
      }, "slow");
   });

     $('#left-button').click(function() {
      event.preventDefault();
      $('#content').animate({
        marginLeft: "-=200px"
      }, "slow");
   });
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/GxufhJaRJn2SfGb4ilIl?p=preview

I have tried the solutions that I have found online. But my container keeps shifting even though I am trying to fix it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
$('#right-button').click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#content').animate({
    scrollLeft: "+=200px"
  }, "slow");
});

 $('#left-button').click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#content').animate({
    scrollLeft: "-=200px"
  }, "slow");
});
```

Edit, to explain... you need to set its scroll left position.

**[DEMO PLUNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/GxufhJaRJn2SfGb4ilIl?p=preview)**

Comment: How can I disable the button when there is no content to scroll ?

Comment: @Venkat this answer is over 5 years old. However, since I still use StackOverflow constantly, I noticed the question. You can just check the width of the `#content` box, and if it's larger than the `.internal` widths together, disable the buttons. Check here: https://jsfiddle.net/4d9uoe85/ - try deleting the `.internal` elements until there are only 3 left, and it should disable the buttons when you re-run it.

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for `scrollLeft` not `marginLeft`:

```
$('#right-button').click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#content').animate({
    scrollLeft: "+=200px"
  }, "slow");
});

 $('#left-button').click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#content').animate({
    scrollLeft: "-=200px"
  }, "slow");
});
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZdCw7IEYdV5YVeGg33oX?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @Vennik is truely awesome,
But in my case i used it bit differently, As i used Material Design and was making API call to display Image Carousal ,
I did in this way ,
First part is Carousel or Slider code and Second part is JS code

```
<!-- Carousel -->
        <span style="cursor:pointer" id="left-button"><i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_left</i></span>&nbsp

        <span style="cursor:pointer" id="right-button"> <i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_right</i></span>

    <div class="bill-screens mdl-shadow--4dp" id="offer-pg-cont">

           <?php for($t=0; $t< count($arr_get_a_user['categories']);$t++){?>
            <div class="bill-pic bill-screen">
              <button class="bill_class" id="bill_<?php echo $t ?>"  onClick="display_image()">

                <img class="bill-screen-image" src="<?php echo $btn_img1; ?>">
             </button>

            </div>
           <?php }?>

        </div>

. . . . . . . . .  .

<script data-require="jquery" data-semver="2.1.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Carausol JS 

   $('#right-button').click(function() {
      event.preventDefault();
      $('#offer-pg-cont').animate({
        scrollLeft: "+=200px"
      }, "slow");
   });

     $('#left-button').click(function() {
      event.preventDefault();
      $('#offer-pg-cont').animate({
        scrollLeft: "-=200px"
      }, "slow");
   });
    </script>
```