# Scroll ag-grid table on button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am using ag-grid (https://www.ag-grid.com/) to implement a complex table in my React app. I am using the pinned version of ag-grid table (https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-pinning/#gsc.tab=0).

I want to place two buttons (for left & right) besides the table and scroll the unpinned part of the table horizontally on button click. I didn't find any api of ag-grid which allows me to scroll the grid/table manually (e.g. on button click).

How can I accomplish this?
You may fork the plunker available on above link for pinned table.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25028040/5187323 - this question should guide you in the right direction, even though it is about jquery and not react

Comment: I was able to implement the functionality. Here is the link: https://plnkr.co/edit/t04eIwbpeG9YBeafJw82?p=preview