# Horizontal Scroll Using Buttons in VueJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, scroll

I'm looking to achieve horizontal scroll using buttons in VueJS. I have a container which has several divs stacked horizontally and I want to scroll through them using the buttons.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25028040/jquery-horizontal-scroll-using-buttons) is an identical thread on SO for JQuery. [This demo](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/GxufhJaRJn2SfGb4ilIl?p=preview) is the solution in JQuery. It should illustrate the effect I'm after.

**How can I achieve that effect using VueJS?**

Some libraries I have already taken a look at include [vue-scroll-to](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-scroll-to) and [jump](https://github.com/callmecavs/jump.js).

- Vue-scroll-to requires the user to specify an element to scroll to whereas I want to horizontally scroll within a specific element by a set amount of pixels.
- Jump allows one to scroll over a defined amount of pixels but only works vertically and appears to only scroll on the window.

EDIT: I found a little library that accomplishes this in VanillaJS: https://github.com/tarun-dugar/easy-scroll

Comment: I understood that you want 2 buttons.Left scroll and Right scroll right?

Comment: @roliroli yep that's correct. Ideally, one would click the right button and it would scroll that element to the right by a set amount of pixels and when the left button is clicked the element is scrolled to the left.

Comment: ok i am going to create a sandbox example hold on

Answer (score 19):

> I made a sandbox for this: [see it here](https://jz38xyr559.codesandbox.io)

The logic is this:

```
scroll_left() {
  let content = document.querySelector(".wrapper-box");
  content.scrollLeft -= 50;
},
scroll_right() {
  let content = document.querySelector(".wrapper-box");
  content.scrollLeft += 40;
}
```

You have a wrapper and you increasing/decreasing the `scrollLeft` property

The full code can be found [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/jz38xyr559)

Comment: This is great; however, would you know of an elegant way of animating the scroll?

Comment: I will accept your answer; however, before I do that it would be good to make clear that the solution doesn't animate in  the same way the demo I linked to does. I also would suggest you edit your answer to use [refs](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-refs) instead of  "document.querySelector" to select the elements since it's a more "Vue way" of doing things per my question. It's also the method I intend on using in my code :)

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking for horizontal smooth scroll animation in javascript itself without using any library.

Use `scrollTo` with `behavior: 'smooth'`

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
el: '#app',

data: {
  scrollAmount: 0,
},

methods: {
scrollLeft: function () {
      const menu = this.$refs.menu
       menu.scrollTo({
      left: this.scrollAmount += 200,
      behavior: 'smooth',
    })
    },

scrollRight: function () {
      const menu = this.$refs.menu
       menu.scrollTo({
      left: this.scrollAmount -= 200,
      behavior: 'smooth',
    })
    }
},
mounted() {}
})
```

```css
body {
    margin: 3em;
}

* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
} 

.menu-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 310px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 1em auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

.menu   {
  height: 120px;
  background: #f3f3f3;
  box-sizing: border-box;

  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
    
.item {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    outline: 1px dotted gray;
    padding: 1em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

 
.paddle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 3em;
}
.left-paddle {
    left: 0;
}
.right-paddle {
    right: 0;
}
.hidden {
    display: none;
}

.print {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 500px;
}
    
span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app" class="menu-wrapper">
   <ul class="menu" ref="menu">
    <li class="item">1</li>
    <li class="item">2</li>
    <li class="item">3</li>
    <li class="item">4</li>
    <li class="item">5</li>
    <li class="item">6</li>
    <li class="item">7</li>
    <li class="item">8</li>
    <li class="item">9</li>
    <li class="item">10</li>
    <li class="item">11</li>
    <li class="item">12</li>
    <li class="item">13</li>
  </ul>
  
    <div class="paddles">
    <button class="left-paddle paddle" @click="scrollRight"> -
        </button>
      
        <button class="right-paddle paddle" @click="scrollLeft">
          >
        </button>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use JavaScript only, using the example you gave I converted it to JavaScript only and here's the Codepen for it.

https://codepen.io/immad-hamid/pen/yEmayr

This is the JavaScript that can replace the example that you sent.

```
const rightBtn = document.querySelector('#right-button');
const leftBtn = document.querySelector('#left-button');
const content = document.querySelector('#content');

rightBtn.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  content.scrollLeft += 300;
  event.preventDefault();
});

leftBtn.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  content.scrollLeft -= 300;
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

For the animation you have to use something... Can you do that?

Comment: Thanks for this - works beautifully. Would you be able to explain how I would achieve the animated scroll effect shown in the demo I linked to in my post?

Comment: You are welcome. I just got a bit busy, some important work came up.

You can search for JavaScript animations and create a common method for animation and using the addEventListener send values to that method to animate.

and let me know if you are able to do it and if not then I'll show it to you by tomorrow.

Comment: Sorry for responding late, I actually forgot that I had to get back to you. So were you able to do it?

Comment: No worries, I actually found a lovely lightweight library in Vanilla JS that accomplishes everything I need (with animation)! https://github.com/tarun-dugar/easy-scroll

Answer (score 0):

There's also this example from codepen

`$ Here's the link`
https://codepen.io/wa23/pen/pObyrq

here's the important things:
HTML (pug)

```
link(href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:200,300,400" rel="stylesheet")


h1 Vue Carousel
script#v-carousel(type="x/template")
  .card-carousel-wrapper
    .card-carousel--nav__left(
      @click="moveCarousel(-1)"
      :disabled="atHeadOfList"
    )
    .card-carousel
      .card-carousel--overflow-container
        .card-carousel-cards(:style="{ transform: 'translateX' + '(' + currentOffset + 'px' + ')'}")
          .card-carousel--card(v-for="item in items")
            img(src="https://placehold.it/200x200")
            .card-carousel--card--footer
              p {{ item.name }}
              p.tag(v-for="(tag,index) in item.tag" :class="index > 0 ? 'secondary' : ''") {{ tag }}
    .card-carousel--nav__right(
      @click="moveCarousel(1)"
      :disabled="atEndOfList"
    )
#app 
  carousel
```

Css (Scss)

```
$vue-navy: #2c3e50;
$vue-navy-light: #3a5169;
$vue-teal: #42b883;
$vue-teal-light: #42b983;
$gray: #666a73;
$light-gray: #f8f8f8;


body {
  background: $light-gray;
  color: $vue-navy;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif; 
}

.card-carousel-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 20px 0 40px;
  color: $gray;
}

.card-carousel {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 640px;
  
  &--overflow-container {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  &--nav__left,
  &--nav__right {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-top: 2px solid $vue-teal;
    border-right: 2px solid $vue-teal;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0 20px;
    transition: transform 150ms linear;
    &[disabled] {
      opacity: 0.2;
      border-color: black;
    }
  }
  
  &--nav__left {
    transform: rotate(-135deg);
    &:active {
      transform: rotate(-135deg) scale(0.9);
    }
  }
  
  &--nav__right {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    &:active {
      transform: rotate(45deg) scale(0.9);
    }
  }
}

.card-carousel-cards {
  display: flex;
  transition: transform 150ms ease-out;
  transform: translatex(0px);
 
  .card-carousel--card {
    margin: 0 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 15px 0 rgba(40,44,53,.06), 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(40,44,53,.08);
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    z-index: 3;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    
    &:first-child {
      margin-left: 0;
    }
    
    &:last-child {
      margin-right: 0;
    }
    
    img {
      vertical-align: bottom;
      border-top-left-radius: 4px;
      border-top-right-radius: 4px;
      transition: opacity 150ms linear;
      user-select: none;
      
      &:hover {
        opacity: 0.5;
      }
    }
    
    &--footer {
      border-top: 0;
      padding: 7px 15px;
      
      p {
        padding: 3px 0;
        margin: 0;
        margin-bottom: 2px;
        font-size: 19px;
        font-weight: 500;
        color: $vue-navy;
        user-select: none;
        
        &.tag {
          font-size: 11px;
          font-weight: 300;
          padding: 4px;
          background: rgba(40,44,53,.06);
          display: inline-block;
          position: relative;
          margin-left: 4px;
          color: $gray;
          
          &:before {
            content:"";
            float:left;
            position:absolute;
            top:0;
            left: -12px;
            width:0;
            height:0;
            border-color:transparent rgba(40,44,53,.06) transparent transparent;
            border-style:solid;
            border-width:8px 12px 12px 0;
        }
          &.secondary {
            margin-left: 0;
            border-left: 1.45px dashed white;
            &:before {
              display: none !important;
            }
          }
        
          &:after {
            content:"";
            position:absolute;
            top:8px;
            left:-3px;
            float:left;
            width:4px;
            height:4px;
            border-radius: 2px;
            background: white;
            box-shadow:-0px -0px 0px #004977;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3.6em;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  color: $vue-teal;
}
```

JS

```
Vue.component("carousel", {
  template: "#v-carousel",
  data() {
    return {
      currentOffset: 0,
      windowSize: 3,
      paginationFactor: 220,
      items: [
        {name: 'Kin Khao', tag: ["Thai"]},
        {name: 'Jū-Ni', tag: ["Sushi", "Japanese", "$$$$"]},
        {name: 'Delfina', tag: ["Pizza", "Casual"]},
        {name: 'San Tung', tag: ["Chinese", "$$"]},
        {name: 'Anchor Oyster Bar', tag: ["Seafood", "Cioppino"]},
        {name: 'Locanda', tag: ["Italian"]},
        {name: 'Garden Creamery', tag: ["Ice cream"]},
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    atEndOfList() {
      return this.currentOffset <= (this.paginationFactor * -1) * (this.items.length - this.windowSize);
    },
    atHeadOfList() {
      return this.currentOffset === 0;
    },
  },
  methods: {
    moveCarousel(direction) {
      // Find a more elegant way to express the :style. consider using props to make it truly generic
      if (direction === 1 && !this.atEndOfList) {
        this.currentOffset -= this.paginationFactor;
      } else if (direction === -1 && !this.atHeadOfList) {
        this.currentOffset += this.paginationFactor;
      }
    },
  }
});

new Vue({
  el:"#app"
});
```

edit: Sorry for not answering soon because I was very busy these days