# How to scroll Tabs in VueJS with Bootstrap-vue

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I have a VueJS with bootstrap-vue project.
A list of tabs gets rendered but it is larger than the width of the parent. So I want to have a pair of buttons to scroll the list from left to right.

I found this example which I got working in my own project. 
[Horizontal Scroll Using Buttons in VueJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51222035/horizontal-scroll-using-buttons-in-vuejs)
But I can not get it to work with the tabs.

In the methods I target .nav-tabs because that is a class that gets rendered to the DOM. I tried to figure it out with .$refs but could not get to the actual element because that element is only visible once rendered.

Can someone please help to get the tabs scrolling.

https://jsfiddle.net/timmyl/xg8j7knb/19/

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="container">
    <b-row class="wrap" ref="wrap">
      <b-tabs content-class="mt-3">
        <b-tab v-for="category in categories" v-bind:title="category.name" :key="category.id">
        </b-tab>
        <b-tab>
          Content
        </b-tab>
      </b-tabs>
    </b-row>
    <b-row>
      <button @click="scroll_left">Scroll Left</button>
      <button @click="scroll_right">Scroll Right</button>
    </b-row>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
methods: {
     scroll_left() {
      let content = document.querySelector(".nav-tabs");
      content.scrollLeft -= 50;
    },
    scroll_right() {
      let content = document.querySelector(".nav-tabs");
      content.scrollLeft += 50;
    }
```

```
.tab-panel {
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.nav-tabs {
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you just need to tweak your css a bit as currently the content of the list is expanding to full screen and you need to add the `overflow` property in order the content to be scrollable,

so here what you are missing:

```
.nav-tabs {
flex-wrap: nowrap;
white-space: nowrap;
max-width: 500px;
overflow: auto;
}
```

I just modified your sandbox and add the the above property to `.nav-tabs`

https://jsfiddle.net/Ljk5a62v/

Comment: hey @kashalo can u plz tell me how cam i make tab content scrollable, i used a custom class as wrapper to tab-content, used `height:100%, overflow-y:auto` but still not working.