# Horizontal Scroll Buttons Like Apple

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

I'm trying to make a horizontal scroll navbar with left-right buttos like apple.com/ipod or medium.com

I searched a lot but none of solutions are working. Some of them working good with jQuery 2 but are not working on latest version. How can simply do that?

My code is simply that:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_menu_horizontal_scroll.asp

Old -not working- solution here
[Jquery horizontal Scroll using buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25028040/jquery-horizontal-scroll-using-buttons)

Comment: Please include a [mcve].

Comment: Please include all code relevant to the question, in the question itself. Also please provide a more details than "not working". What specifically is not working? How is it not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want to achieve?

```js
const SLIDE_AMOUNT = 200;

const scrollMenu = document.querySelector('.scrollmenu');
const scrollMenuInner = scrollMenu.querySelector('.scrollmenu-inner');

const leftBtn = document.querySelector('.scrollmenu-btn-left');
const rightBtn = document.querySelector('.scrollmenu-btn-right');

leftBtn.addEventListener('click', slideLeft);
rightBtn.addEventListener('click', slideRight);

function getOffset() {
  const offset = parseInt(scrollMenuInner.style.marginLeft.slice(0, -2));
  return isNaN(offset) ? 0 : offset;
}

function slideRight() {
  const offset = getOffset();

  const diff = scrollMenuInner.clientWidth + offset - scrollMenu.clientWidth
  if (diff >= SLIDE_AMOUNT) {
    scrollMenuInner.style.marginLeft = `${offset - SLIDE_AMOUNT}px`;
  } else if (diff < SLIDE_AMOUNT && diff > 0) {
    scrollMenuInner.style.marginLeft = `${offset - diff}px`;
  }
};

function slideLeft() {
  const offset = getOffset();

  if (Math.abs(offset) >= SLIDE_AMOUNT) {
    scrollMenuInner.style.marginLeft = `${offset + SLIDE_AMOUNT}px`;
  } else if (Math.abs(offset) < SLIDE_AMOUNT && offset < 0) {
    scrollMenuInner.style.marginLeft = '0px';
  }
}
```

```css
body { font-family: sans-serif; }

.scrollmenu-container {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.scrollmenu {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #222;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.scrollmenu-inner {
  display: inline-flex;
  transition: margin-left 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.scrollmenu:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 200%;
  top: -50%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events : none;
  box-shadow:
    10px 0 20px #222 inset,
    -10px 0 20px #222 inset;
}

.scrollmenu-container button {
  background-color: #555;
  color: #ccc;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
}

.scrollmenu-container button:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.scrollmenu a {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.scrollmenu a:hover {
  background-color: #777;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollmenu-container">
  <button class="scrollmenu-btn-left">&lt;</button>
  <div class="scrollmenu">
    <div class="scrollmenu-inner">
      <a href="#home">Home</a>
      <a href="#news">News</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      <a href="#about">About</a>
      <a href="#home">Home 2</a>
      <a href="#news">News 3</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact 3</a>
      <a href="#about">About 4</a>
      <a href="#home">Home 5</a>
      <a href="#news">News 6</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact 7</a>
      <a href="#about">About 8</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="scrollmenu-btn-right">&gt;</button>
</div>
```

EDIT: Here is a simple jQuery version:

```js
$scrollMenu = $('.scrollmenu');

$('.btn-left').click(function() {
  $scrollMenu.animate({
    scrollLeft: '-=200px'
  }, 'slow');
});

$('.btn-right').click(function() {
  $scrollMenu.animate({
    scrollLeft: '+=200px'
  }, 'slow');
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.scrollmenu-container {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.scrollmenu {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #222;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.scrollmenu-container button {
  background-color: #555;
  color: #ccc;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
}

.scrollmenu-container button:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.scrollmenu a {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.scrollmenu a:hover {
  background-color: #777;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scrollmenu-container">
  <button class="btn-left">&lt;</button>
  <div class="scrollmenu">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#news">News</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#home">Home 2</a>
    <a href="#news">News 3</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact 3</a>
    <a href="#about">About 4</a>
    <a href="#home">Home 5</a>
    <a href="#news">News 6</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact 7</a>
    <a href="#about">About 8</a>
  </div>
  <button class="btn-right">&gt;</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes it was! I've tried same maybe hundred times but IDK what was wrong :/ You're my hero <3