# How Scroll table horizontally to the last td one by one on right arrow click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to scroll the table one by one td on right button click and again in reverse on click on left button. I have used `.animate` on table but scroll position doesn't move, only whole table moves and this is only fist time. Please help I'm not getting it. Thank you.

```js
$('.right').click(function() {
  $('.table').animate({
    right: '120px',
  })
});
```

```css
.table {
  border: 1px solid #dcddde;
  border-top: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 800px;
  position: relative;
}

.table-responsive {
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 600px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="left">left</button>
<button class="right">right</button>
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table border="1" cellspacing="0" class="table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th style="width:auto">Quantity in piece(s)</th>
        <th>Logistics</th>
        <th>MOQ</th>
        <th>100-199</th>
        <th>200-299</th>
        <th>300-399</th>
        <th>400+</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="">South Africa Warehouse (€ )</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span class="included">Included</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span class="included">100</span>
        </td>
        <td>€23.0000</td>
        <td>€23.0000</td>
        <td>€23.0000</td>
        <td>€23.0000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lead Time (Days)</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>34</td>
        <td>34</td>
        <td>323</td>
        <td>23</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

To make this work you need to animate the `scrollLeft` property of the overflowed div, not the `right` position of the `table` itself.

You can track which `td` you need to align with by simply setting a class on the element and moving that class depending on which button was clicked. Then you can retrieve its `position()` and call `animate()`, something like the below example. Note that I added some more columns to the table to make the scroll effect more obvious.

```js
var $table = $('.table-responsive');

$('.move').click(function() {
  var $target = $table.find('td.target');
  if ($target.length == 0)
    $target = $table.find('td:first');
    
  $target = $target[$(this).data('dir')]('td');
  if ($target.length == 0) 
    return;  
  
  $('.table-responsive').stop().animate({ scrollLeft: $target.position().left })  ;
  $table.find('.target').removeClass('target');
  $target.addClass('target');
});
```

```css
.table {
  border: 1px solid #dcddde;
  border-top: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 800px;
  position: relative;
}

.table-responsive {
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 600px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="move" data-dir="prev">left</button>
<button class="move" data-dir="next">right</button>
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table border="1" cellspacing="0" class="table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th style="width:auto">Quantity in piece(s)</th>
        <th>Logistics</th>
        <th>MOQ</th>
        <th>100-199</th>
        <th>200-299</th>
        <th>300-399</th>
        <th>400+</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="">South Africa Warehouse (€ )</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span class="included">Included</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span class="included">100</span>
        </td>
        <td>€23.0000</td>
        <td>€23.0000</td>
        <td>€23.0000</td>
        <td>€23.0000</td>
        <td>€23.0000</td>
        <td>€23.0000</td>
        <td>€23.0000</td>
        <td>€23.0000</td>
        <td>€23.0000</td>
        <td>€23.0000</td>
        <td>€23.0000</td>
        <td>€23.0000</td>
        <td>€23.0000</td>
        <td>€23.0000</td>
        <td>€23.0000</td>
        <td>€23.0000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lead Time (Days)</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>34</td>
        <td>34</td>
        <td>323</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>34</td>
        <td>34</td>
        <td>323</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>34</td>
        <td>34</td>
        <td>323</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>34</td>
        <td>34</td>
        <td>323</td>
        <td>23</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I'm getting $target[$(...).data(...)] is not a function this

Comment: Actually I'm using your code in reactjs. I have made function move(){ you whole code } and the calling move function onclick to class move buttons

Answer (score 1):

Hi you could try using [scrollLeft](https://api.jquery.com/scrollleft/), here a working example:

```js
$('.right').click(function(){
  $('.table-responsive').animate(
  { scrollLeft: '+=50' }, 100)
});

$('.left').click(function(){
$('.table-responsive').animate(
  { scrollLeft: '-=50' }, 100)
});
```

```css
.table {
    border: 1px solid #dcddde;
    border-top: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width:800px;
    position:relative;
}
.table-responsive{
 overflow:scroll;
 width:600px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="left">left</button>
<button class="right">right</button>
<div class="table-responsive">
   <table border="1" cellspacing="0" class="table">
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <th style="width:auto">Quantity in piece(s)</th>
            <th>Logistics</th>
            <th>MOQ</th>
            <th>100-199</th>
            <th>200-299</th>
            <th>300-399</th>
            <th>400+</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
               <div class="">South Africa Warehouse (€ )</div>
            </td>
            <td>
               <span class="included">Included</span>
            </td>
            <td>
               <span class="included">100</span>
            </td>
            <td>€23.0000</td>
            <td>€23.0000</td>
            <td>€23.0000</td>
            <td>€23.0000</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Lead Time (Days)</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>34</td>
            <td>34</td>
            <td>323</td>
            <td>23</td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [this answer to an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25028040/jquery-horizontal-scroll-using-buttons):

Switch your JS to:

```
$('.right').click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.table-responsive').animate({
    scrollLeft: "+=120px"
  }, "slow");
});

 $('.left').click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.table-responsive').animate({
    scrollLeft: "-=120px"
  }, "slow");
});
```

Keeping your html and css the same.

Result:

```js
$('.right').click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.table-responsive').animate({
    scrollLeft: "+=120px"
  }, "slow");
});

 $('.left').click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.table-responsive').animate({
    scrollLeft: "-=120px"
  }, "slow");
});
```

```css
.table {
  border: 1px solid #dcddde;
  border-top: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 800px;
  position: relative;
}

.table-responsive {
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 600px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="left">left</button>
<button class="right">right</button>
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table border="1" cellspacing="0" class="table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th style="width:auto">Quantity in piece(s)</th>
        <th>Logistics</th>
        <th>MOQ</th>
        <th>100-199</th>
        <th>200-299</th>
        <th>300-399</th>
        <th>400+</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="">South Africa Warehouse (€ )</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span class="included">Included</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span class="included">100</span>
        </td>
        <td>€23.0000</td>
        <td>€23.0000</td>
        <td>€23.0000</td>
        <td>€23.0000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lead Time (Days)</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>34</td>
        <td>34</td>
        <td>323</td>
        <td>23</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: What if the width of the cells changes depending on their content?

Comment: Right now, using the code above it would still just scroll by the set increment (120px). It sounds like @Varun's solution might be a better starting point. That scrolls the first column out of view (rather than next into view) - assuming you haven't scrolled manually yet.

Answer (score -2):

You can maintain the td position in a variable and move to the direction accordingly.
I have calculated the column width beforehand and scrolled based on that.

Here is the working solution..

```js
var pos = 0, // holds the current td position
  columnCount = $('.table th').length, // columns count
  columnWidth = [];

// collect all column width and save in array
$.each($('.table th'), function(ind, elem) {
  columnWidth.push($(elem).width());
});

$('.right').click(function() {
  if (pos === columnCount - 1) return false; // dont scroll after last td

  pos++;

  var
    col = columnWidth.slice(0, pos),
    sum = col.reduce((pv, cv) => {
      return pv + (parseFloat(cv) || 0);
    }, 0); // calculate how much it has to be scroll to the right

  $('.table').animate({
    right: sum + 'px',
  });
});

$('.left').click(function() {
  if (pos === 0) return false; // dont scroll beyond first td

  pos--;

  var
    col = columnWidth.slice(0, pos),
    sum = col.reduce((pv, cv) => {
      return pv + (parseFloat(cv) || 0);
    }, 0);  // calculate how much it has to be scroll to the left

  $('.table').animate({
    right: sum + 'px',
  });
});
```

```css
.table {
  border: 1px solid #dcddde;
  border-top: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 800px;
  position: relative;
}

.table-responsive {
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 600px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="left">left</button>
<button class="right">right</button>
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table border="1" cellspacing="0" class="table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th style="width:auto">Quantity in piece(s)</th>
        <th>Logistics</th>
        <th>MOQ</th>
        <th>100-199</th>
        <th>200-299</th>
        <th>300-399</th>
        <th>400+</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="">South Africa Warehouse (€ )</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span class="included">Included</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span class="included">100</span>
        </td>
        <td>€23.0000</td>
        <td>€23.0000</td>
        <td>€23.0000</td>
        <td>€23.0000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lead Time (Days)</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>34</td>
        <td>34</td>
        <td>323</td>
        <td>23</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```