# Horizontal scrolling issue along with next and previous buttons

Tags: jquery, dom, scroll

With jQuery, I have created a horizontal `div` tag and I want to scroll this `div` with the help of next and previous buttons.

I have the code which is working for vertical scroll but how to apply the same code for *horizontal* scroll?

```js
function scrollSmoothToBottom(id) {
    var div = document.getElementById(id);
    $('#' + id).animate({
        scrollTop: div.scrollHeight - div.clientHeight
    }, 500);
}

function scrollSmoothToTop(id) {
    var div = document.getElementById(id);
    $('#' + id).animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 500);
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25028040/jquery-horizontal-scroll-using-buttons)

Comment: `element.scrollLeft` property can do thing for you

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure this code work or not, you have to check and let me know if works

```
function scrollSmoothToRight (id) {
       var div = document.getElementById(id);
       $('#' + id).animate({
       scrollLeft: div.scrollWidth - div.clientWidth // set this value to 0 for Left
       }, 500);
       }
```

Comment: actually i want scroll the div pixel-wise , your code is working fine for left to right , but not working for right to left .. how to do it ????

Comment: for more information you can check out 
[this answer ][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8905832/jquery-scrollright#8906007

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace `scrollTop` to `scrollLeft`, `scrollHeight` to `scrollWidth` and `clientHeight` to `clientWidth`.